# javascript variable referencing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So I am trying to set a metric for Universal Analytics. Here is the JavaScript that I am using:

```
function setCustomMetric(index, value){
  if(typeof index === "number" && index > 0 && typeof value === "number"){
    var metricIndex = 'metric' + index;
    ga('set', {metricIndex: value});
  }
}
```

When I send the function 1 and 5 as the respective parameters I get this return
My problem is that it is sending ga("set", {metricIndex: 5}); rather than ga("set", {metric1: 5}); I could use a switch statement for the 20 possible indexes but I would rather not have to hard code all of the possibilities. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var metricIndex = 'metric' + index;
var myObject={};

myObject[metricIndex]=value;
ga('set', myObject);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks and excuse my lack of knowledge in JS